# firebase v3 - google auth "internal-error"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to migrate my google-auth-only project from firebase 2.x to 3.0 using the web-sdk example from:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/google-redirect.html

After setting up the initialisation-code with apiKey (via Google-Developer-Console - used the server-option) and all the other needed options, i use the "login with google"-button.
After this, an redirect-screen appears, then redirecting back to starting page and getting an **"auth/internal-error"**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend importing your project in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) rather than configuring keys manually if possible, but appreciate there are some cases where that isn't ideal.

For the API key, try switching to the "Browser" type key rather than the "Server" one for anything running in the browser, and make sure it is approved for the domain you are using.

Google Sign In will need a client ID as well. The easiest way to implement is to use the [`signInWithPopUp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#before_you_begin) method, but there are instructions for [manually configuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually) the Google Sign In lib too.

If you do need to create a client ID, you can see the full instructions in the [Google Sign In documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project).

Comment: thx for your answer. I cant use Browser, because the API-Key discards after 24h.
signInWithPopUp isnt a solution, because on mobile it is not recommed with pop-ups.

Comment: I believe the pop up works well on mobile, but understand your concern. Re the other part, how do you mean discards after 24 hours? There isn't an expiry on the API keys.

Comment: you are right concerning the 24h expire. it shows, when i create i new one. sorry for this wrong statement.
i now tried browser, but get: "this domain is not authorized fpr OAuth operations, edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console". but my domain is in this list.

Comment: Marcel, when you get this error you have to go to the Firebase console > Auth > Sign-in methods > OAuth redirect domains and there enter the domain where you are hosting your JS application. Please reply back if that doesn't work.

Comment: i added my domain to the list. it is an subdomain. when i dont do this, i get the "not authorized for your firebase project"-error 2 times! when i add my domain to the list, i get this error only once. sometimes it comes from "iframe.js". btw: when i use the browser-api-key, i cant start my app from localhost. error: "This app, identified by the domain where it's hosted, is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the provided API key. Review your key configuration in the Google API console". by using server-api-key it works from localhost. but then i get "internal error".

Comment: 1) Try adding your domain without the subdomain and see if that works. e.g. instead of 'sub.domain.com' just whitelist 'domain.com'

Comment: 2) For the browser key -> go to the Google API console console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials , select your firebase project from the top bar if it is not selected yet, and open the browser key you are using in your project. Then look under "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers" and ensure that the list is empty (accepts all)

Comment: now i use the browser-api-key without any referrers and created an oauth2 web-client in google-developer-console.
i copied the client-id and secret into firebase-input-fields in google-auth-area.
no errors are shown on app-start. but clicking on login with google leads to an accounts.google error-site: Error: redirect_uri_mismatch the site with the broken robot :-)

Comment: solved: after 1h it works. maybe, the changes took some time... thx at all